# Woocommerce_single_product_summary hook is not working with flatsome template. How to resolve this?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to running below code inside my code snippet plugin editor looks like below:
[image]

My code snippet is so simple like below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_option', 15);

function add_custom_option() {
    echo "Hello here";
}
```

So what I am trying to do is add "Hello here" line after the product price on single product detail page. I wanted to do this using woocommerce hook.

**As far as I know the theme is overriding my changes and not letting me place my custom message.**

I've use the below theme:
[Flatsome theme](https://themeforest.net/item/flatsome-multipurpose-responsive-woocommerce-theme/5484319)

Also, I've found the theme related doc here. If this will help anyone to resolve my issue:
[plugin doc](https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/385-hooks#flatsome_product_block)

Can anyone please help me to how to execute my custom woocommerce hook and not let theme to override my changes. As I can't see my changes on the website.

Please help as I've spend quite sometime to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do this with hook i have an idea.  First  you have to go wp-content>plugins>woocommerce>template>single-product>price.php. Second you have to copy this file and you have to go wp-content>themes>current theme folder > woocommerce. if you have a single-product directory paste this file. If you don't have a single-product crate single-product directory and paste. Now you can change this file like this:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

?>
<p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 
'price' ) ); ?>"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

echo "Hello here";
```